# django testing passing request.user to foreignKey field, "Event.creator" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-testing

I am trying to write test for a view that creates an event model object. The event model contains a foreignKey field that references auth user as the creator of the model object. In the test I tried logging in the user which I assumed would set the request.user to the user logged in. The view that is being tested references request.user when creating the event the works fine when triggered normally through ajax but when I run the test I keep getting the error below. Also I have tried creating the user within the test function instead of referencing the user created at "class.setupTestData()", same error.

error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x108ae9cc0>>": "Event.creator" must be a "User" instance.
```

model

```
    class Event(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        event_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='attendees')
        start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
        start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
        end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
        end_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        description = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

view

```
    def createEvent(request):
        # dec vars
        event_title = str(request.POST['event-title']).title()
        event_type = str(request.POST['event-type'])
        event_location = str(request.POST['event-location'])
        event_description = str(request.POST['event-description'])
        event_start_date = str(request.POST['event-start-date'])
        event_start_time = str(request.POST['event-start-time'])
        event_end_date = str(request.POST['event-end-date'])
        event_end_time = str(request.POST['event-end-time'])
        creator = request.user

        # create event
        Event.objects.create(
            name=event_title,
            event_type=event_type,
            creator=creator,
            location=event_location,
            description=event_description,
            start_date=event_start_date,
            start_time=event_start_time,
            end_date=event_end_date,
            end_time=event_end_time
        )

        # #create response
        response = {
            'status': 'success',
        }

        # send reponse JSON
        return JsonResponse(response)
```

test

```
def test_create_event(self):
    today = timezone.now()
    user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

    # login user
    self.c.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)

    # Check event create
    response = self.c.post('/event/create/', {
        'event-title': 'test create event',
        'event-type': 'combat',
        'event-location': 'ltt 9455',
        'event-description': lorem.paragraph,
        'event-start-date': today.date(),
        'event-end-date': today.date(),
        'event-end-time': today.time(),
        'event-start-time': today.time()
    })

    self.assertTrue()
```

Comment: I think I found the solution to this using Django's RequestFactory I'll comment back if it works.

Answer (score 1):

`user.password` is the *hashed* password, therefore you can't use it when you call `client.login()`

You could use the actual password when you call `login`

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
self.client.login(username=user.username, password='actual_password')
```

Or you could use [`client.force_login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) instead, which does not required the password.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
self.client.force_login(user)
```

Note that your failing test has uncovered a problem with your view. If an anonymous user uses that view, the `ValueError` will cause a 500 server error. The easiest fix would be to use the `login_required` decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def createEvent(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the force login worked. In the templates I did use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` tag to hide the button  to prevent a not logged in user from creating an event. Should I still use the `@login_required` decorator in conjunction with the template tag on views that require an logged user or is that overkill.

Comment: I would check in the view and not rely on the template. Hiding the button in the template is good, but it doesn't stop a user from manually submitting the request.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice I went ahead and added the decorators I'm just gonna use both decorators and template tags.